# Hyperref capitalizes the URL

Tags: hyperref, capitalization

I was trying to embed a link (which contains both upper-case and lower-case letters) on a text. Here is the code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{http://goo.gl/maps/vcZfr}{Publications}

%% The above embedding could not redirect me to the correct link. 
%% Instead it led me to https://goo.gl/MAPS/VCZFR
\end{document}
```

Could you help me out with why some letters got capitalized?

Comment: I have no problem finding Gloria Jean's Coffees...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the minimal example doesn't reflect the suggested output. Based on the OP's comment, the `\href` was placed inside a sectional unit which reformatted the link.

Answer (score 8):

`hyperref` does not do anything like this. The MWE of the question gives the following in the PDF file (pdflatex):

```
/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(http://goo.gl/maps/vcZfr)>>
```

The URL is unchanged. Maybe the `\href` is inside an argument, which is uppercased later (e.g. via `\MakeUppercase`).

A workaround is a protected macro, which is not affected by `\MakeUppercase` or `\uppercase`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\protected\def\hrefvcZfr{\href{http://goo.gl/maps/vcZfr}}

\begin{document}

\href{http://goo.gl/maps/vcZfr}{Publications}
\MakeUppercase{\hrefvcZfr{Publications}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes I just found it. I was just going to delete the question.

The thing was the class file I was using capitalizes the header of the section. Publication was the section header. And I wanted to embed a link onto that.

Anyways thanks.