# Add \href in \subsection{} make the url become capital

Tags: capitalization, url, href

I add \href in \subsection{}, this make the url become all capital, how can I deal with this?

For example, I use \subsection{\href{http://finance.sina.com.cn/roll/2018-06-30/doc-iheqpwqz3115534.shtml}{some text}} and run latex, it shows like this. [image]
And It contains an url.

Then when I click the link, the  url becomes http://finance.sina.com.cn/ROLL/2018-06-30/DOC-IHEQPWQZ3115534.SHTML like this:
[image]
in the web-browser. 
All the letters become capital, this url cannot open the right website.

What can I do to fix this? I want the url can open the right website. Thank you.

Comment: Copying the example in your post body, I do not replicate the behaviour you describe. Please could you produce a [Minimum Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) which reproduces the problem?

Comment: An example that could reproduce this is `\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{\href{http://example.com/lowercase}{some text}}

\uppercase{\href{http://example.com/lowercase}{some text}}
\end{document}`

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274734/35864 can help

Comment: The work-around in the linked question seems to work here is well, `\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\protected\def\mylink{http://example.com/lowercase}

\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{\href{\mylink}{some text}}

\uppercase{\href{\mylink}{some text}}
\end{document}` but maybe there is something cleverer.

Comment: Sir, but if you use \href in \subsection{} like \subseciont{\href{}{}}, all the letters will become upper case.

Comment: Well the second code with the work-around I posted avoids the URL becoming capitalised. Naturally the "some text" still becomes "SOME TEXT" because that is how your document class formats section headings. What exactly is the output you want? And what does your document look like (show an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), please).

Comment: Since the url becomes the url becomes http://finance.sina.com.cn/ROLL/2018-06-30/DOC-IHEQPWQZ3115534.SHTML, it cannot open the right page. I want it still be http://finance.sina.com.cn/roll/2018-06-30/doc-iheqpwqz3115534.shtml where the letters are still in lower case, and this can open the pages correctly. Thank you.

Comment: I add some MWE in the question, can you please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Use  `\lowercase{\href{http://example.com/lowercase}{some text}} `

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work! :-
`\subsection{\texorpdfstring{\lowercase{\href{http://finance.sina.com.cn/roll/2018-06-30/doc-iheqpwqz3115534.shtml}{\MakeUppercase{some text}}}}{}}`

Since by default, the whole text in a subsection is in upper-case, hence after wrapping `\lowercase` over whole `\href` part, this upper-case has to be done forcefully (here using `\MakeUppercase`).

Also, `\texorpdfstring` has been used to avoid the warning:
[Hyperref warning - Token not allowed in a PDF string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/)

(There may be other work-arounds too)

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer to a similar question here:
[Hyperref capitalizes the URL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274734/hyperref-capitalizes-the-url)
which worked for me!

Check this example out:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.50cm, right=1.50cm, top=1.50cm, bottom=1.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\runsubsection}[1]{\uppercase {#1} \normalfont}

\protected\def\Myurl{\href{https://drive.google.com/file/d/someUPPERandLowercaseURL123456/view}}

\begin{document}
    Here is an example:\\
    Hover your mouse over the urls to see what url they are representing:\\
    there are the same urls inside the same command($\backslash$runsubsection), but the $\backslash$uppercase command converts the first url to UPPERCASE.\\[10pt]
    
    \runsubsection{\href{https://drive.google.com/file/d/someUPPERandLowercaseURL123456/view}{some Normal Text for url}}\\
    
    \runsubsection{\Myurl{some Normal Text for url}}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add some code here showing what you're talking about?  The question you link to was closed because it looks like OP was putting `\href` in a `\section`, but didn't actually do so in their code, so the answer doesn't really reflect what's happening in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Tried many ways for hours and got myself caught into a simple solution
instead of including a link into subsection. Do the opposite.

Before :
\subsection{\href{sometext.com}{some text}}

Wasn't working because some inbuilt function capitalized the link.

After :
\href{sometext.com}{\subsection{some text}}

This finally worked for me

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).